Proving complement of a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is path connected
Question: Let $S$ be a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then prove/disprove $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S$ is path connected
(Note: $S$ may be any line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ not necessarily any axes! for example, $S$ may be the line defined by parametric equation,$x=-1+2t$, $y=-1+3t$, $z=3$ that is line passing through $(1, 2, 3)$ & $(-1, -1, 3)$)
I like to see geometric approach/visual approach.
My attempt:
for simplicity, I assume $S$ is the line passing through the points $(1, 2,3)$ & $(-1, -1, 3)$. Clearly if $A, B$ are any  two points in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S$, then either we have case(a) or case(b).
Case(a): there exists a straight line passing through $A$ and $B$ which does not intersect the line $S$. So there exists a path joining $A$ & $B$ and the path is contained in $S$.
Case(b): If the straight line passing through $A$ and $B$ interest the line $S$. Then we can take circular path joining $A$ and $B$ or we can take a point $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S$ such that, line passing through $A$ & $C$ does not intersect $S$ and line passing through $C$ & $B$ does not intersect $S$. Hence we get path joining $A$ to $C$ and then $C$ to $B$ and this path is contained in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S$.
Hence from case(a) & case(b) we see that $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S$ is path connected.
Is my approach is correct?,
I know that, I didn't write any path definitions and clearly it is not standard proof. But I am unable to prove it in standard way. Please help me.

This looks fine and probably meets the standard of rigor expected in a topology course.

There is no reason to impose a coordinate system on $\Bbb R^3$ before the line $S$ is established, and if one is handed to you there is no need to actually use that. You can just make up your own coordinate system where $S$ is the $x$-axis.

To me it does not seem rigourous enough to be considered a proof, with all technical details hidden behind "there exist", "we can take" and alike. What if not ?

To me, the easiest way is to use Arthur's comment and the unit circle placed on the plane $x=0$ whose $(0,0,0)$ is the center point. Then, for an arbitrary point, it is easy to thow that you can reach the circle without going through the $x$ axis (orthogonal projection into the $x=0$ plane than to the circle, both having simple analytical expressions).

@Arthur sir, I didn't get what you mean. Is you mean we can take $S$ to any line of our choice.  nicomezi sir, I know it lacks many details to be considered as a solution. But is the approach is correct? Moreover, I can write parametric equations of line passing through $A$ & $C$ and for the line passing through $B$ & $C$ provided points must be given. But, here we just assume arbitrary points and hence for me It's not possible to write definition of path. Can you and Arthur sir, help me.

What was meant is that you don't have to take the standard basis for $\mathbb R^3$ to write the coordinates of your points. Any 3 linearly independent vectors will do, and if one of those 3 vectors is any vector on $S$, then $S$ itself becomes an axis in the new base. In other words, you can rotate and translate the standard basis until the $x$-axis overlaps $S$.

We can't take $S$ to be any line of our choice. That line is given to us in the problem statement. But we can pick our own coordinate system around that line. The end result is functionally equivalent to being able to pick $S$ freely, all the calculations will look exactly the same either way. But the underlying mental model and the flow of the logic is different.

I prefer a piecewise linear path by choosing a point near the missing line if it goes through it. Typically I pick one that is orthogonal to both the missing line and the path I'm trying to create.

:-( I am not getting it. I wish someone help me with both the approach (My approach & by One said by Arthur sir)

Your geometric approach is fine and Arthur's comment is just a hint to make its formulation easier. Equivalently: wlog, $S$ is the $x$-axis, and then, $\Bbb R^3\setminus S=\Bbb R\times A$ is path-connected because so are $\Bbb R$ and $A:=$ the plane minus the origin.

Let $P$ and $Q$ be any two points in $\mathbb R^3\setminus S$. Consider the sphere having the segment $PQ$ as a diameter. On that sphere there are infinitely many (continuum many) great circle arcs from $P$ to $Q$. The line $S$ meets the sphere in at most two points, and each of those points lies on only one of those great circle arcs. Thus all but (at most) two of those arcs are contained in $\mathbb R^3\setminus S$.
More generally, if $\{S_i:i\in I\}$ is a collection of straight lines in $\mathbb R^3$ with $|I|\lt|\mathbb R|$, a similar argument shows that $\mathbb R^3\setminus\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$ is path-connected.

Sir, can you elaborate: 'Thus all but (at most) two of those arcs are contained in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S$ '  how & why? moreover, how from this it follows that $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S$ is path connected?

Briefly: any two points $P$ and $Q$ lie on a sphere; the line $S$ meets the sphere in two points; a sphere minus two points is path-connected. In my answer I spelled it out in detail. $P$ and $Q$ are diametrically opposite points on a sphere. The line $S$ meets that sphere in (at most) two points $X$ and $Y$. There are an infinite number of great circles through $P$ and $Q$; $X$ lies on one of those great circles, $Y$ lies on another. Any of the remaining great circles through $P$ and $Q$, is contained in $\mathbb R^3\setminus S$. Half of that circle provides a path from $P$ to $Q$.

Pick a point $C$ not belonging to the union of the planes defined by $S$ and $A$ or $S$ and $B$. Then the piece-wise linear path
$$
\gamma(t)=A+f(t)\overline{AC}+g(t)\overline{CB},\qquad t\in[0,2],
$$
where $f(t)=t$ for $t\in[0,1]$, $f(t)=1$ for $t\in[1,2]$ and $g(t)=0$ for $t\in[0,1]$, $g(t)=t-1$ for $t\in[1,2]$
is entirely contained in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S$, is continuous and connects the given points.
No coordinates are needed.

Nice, but sir how can we assured that, the path is contained in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S$ and does intersect $S$

Because $C$ is chosen outside of the planes defined by $S$ and $A$ and by $S$ and $B$.The path is made of two segments, neither of them intersecting $S$
